# Basic call using linphone core

Tags: linphone, core-api

I have done Libphone android, and Ios sdk projects build and integration with my application successfully.

[image]

I am trying to run the samples that I got from the downloaded Linphone source code for e.g coreapi/help/helloworld.c. I'm getting an error as shown in attachment. Please guild me how to run these samples.

Comment: I downloaded all required dependencies and trying to do a very simple program as below int main(int argc , char *argv[])
{
    LinphoneFactory *lFactory = linphone_factory_get();
    
    return 0;
}

Comment: Now getting an eror saying 'undefined reference to linphone_factory_get()'